# profiling memory usage using PyFlame

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, python-3.6, memory-profiling

How do I profile memory leak using the pyflame. I have a flask application running on python 3.6. As per my understanding by default it gives CPU flame graphs.

Some of the starting points are -

- https://eng.uber.com/pyflame/
- http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/memoryflamegraphs.html